# Why the editor text doesn't change the text color in XamarinForms

Tags: xamarin.forms, editor, textcolor

I set the property TextColor="White" but when I test the app the textColor of the editor is black

```
<ScrollView HeightRequest="90" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0"    
            IsVisible="{Binding TurnOnPrivacyPolicyMessage}">
   <Editor x:Name="txtMensaje" TextColor="White"  
           BackgroundColor="Transparent" IsEnabled="False" > 
   </Editor>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use your code to test, but I find the Editor TextColor is white, not black.

Because you set Editor BackGroundColor is Transparent, the TextColor is white, you may not see Text clear, so I suggest you can set BackgroundColor as Gray or other to test.

```
<StackLayout>

        <Editor
            x:Name="txtMensaje"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            TextColor="White" />

    </StackLayout>
```

The BackgroundColor is Transparent:

[image]

The BackGroundColor is Gray:

[image]

Comment: I found the answer the problem is when the propyte isEnbaled=flase the text color of editor is black  if the propyte is true the text take the color of textColor Propyte

Comment: @Angle, it is so strange, because you can not enter any characters when Editor isEnable=false, you can do this?

Comment: @Abgel, I test it, as you said that it works, so please share your solution here or mark your solution as answer, or you can mark any reply that help you, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use IsReadOnly instead - "The IsReadonly property does not alter the visual appearance of an Editor, unlike the IsEnabled property that also changes the visual appearance of the Editor to gray."  [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor#prevent-text-entry)